# Unit test of endpoint decorated with Flask @auth.login_required decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking, decorator

I'm using Flask-HTTPAuth for authentication, Flask-login for login and want to add unit tests for endpoint decorated with `@auth.login_required(scheme="Bearer")`:

**endpoints.py**

```
class UserData(Resource):
    @auth.login_required
    def get(self, user_id):
        user = db_models.User.query.get(user_id)
        return result
```

**authent.py**

```
@auth.verify_token
def verify_token(token):
    data = token_serializer.loads(token)
    return data.get("username", False)
```

But got stuck with mocking (it doesn't work):

**test.py**

```
@mock.patch("myapp.auth")
@mock.patch("myapp.db_models.User")
def test_get_user(self, mock_user, mock_login):
    with app.test_client() as client:
        mock_login.verify_token.return_value = TEST_USER["username"]
        mock_login.login_required.return_value = True
        mock_user.query.get.return_value = TEST_USER
        response = client.get("/user/100000")
        self.assertIsNotNone(response)
        self.assertIsInstance(response.get_json(), dict)
```

And the second approach:

**test.py**

```
@mock.patch("myapp.auth.login_required", return_value = True)
@mock.patch("myapp.db_models.User")
def test_get_user(self, mock_user, mock_login):
    with app.test_client() as client:
        mock_user.query.get.return_value = TEST_USER
        response = client.get("/user/100000")
        self.assertIsNotNone(response)
        self.assertIsInstance(response.get_json(), dict)
```

Could you please help me to figure out how to do it in the right way?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Both are totally valid since you don't test the `auth` library it doesn't matter how granular your mocking approach is. Nice attention to details ;)